# Importing Excel/CVS file to Azure SQL DB in which columns have multiple values

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

I have an existing SQL DB in Azure with various tables. I am trying to import an excel/csv file into one of the tables using this link [Import using SSMS][1].

I have figured out how to do this, everything but one thing, which is how to handle columns with multiple values. I am able to control what the delimiter is for multiple values in a column (could be a comma, a ;, a new line or a blank, etc.) However, the values are going to be names like Albert Einstein,Joe DiMaggio, etc.

What delimiter should I use and how can I "tell" the import wizard in SSMS that a column has multiple values, and what the delimiter is?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, multi-character row/column delimiter isn't supported in Azure Data Factory. You need to manage it programmatically.

Since the data source isn't Azure Data Lake storage, you also can't use USQL activity, otherwise you could use it for transformation.

Use program approach using `Custom activity` in Azure Data Factory.